# Haskell Tail Split

Tags: string, haskell, split, tail

this is what I'm trying to do:

If I give 
    `$hello world` I would get `world`

What I am doing is this :

`tail (unwords (words "$hello world"))`
but I'm getting `"hello world"` instead of `world`

What do I have to do to get it right?

Answer (score 8):

You have to apply `unwords` after `tail`, not the other way around.

The intended sequence of steps is (probably) as follows:

1. Break string into list of words
2. Drop the first word from the list
3. Join the remaining words to a string

The way you do it, you split and immediately re-join the words and then you just drop the first character of the resulting string (since a String is just a list of Chars).

Comment: While I like how you point out what the OP is doing wrong, technically this is missing an solution of the problem. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Waldheinz: Incorrect. The solution is the very first line of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're wanting to do is

```
unwords $ tail $ words "$hello world"
```

Working through it in GHCi we get

```
> words "$hello world"
["$hello", "world"]
> tail $ words "$hello world"
["world"]
> unwords $ tail $ words "$hello world"
"world"
```

Answer (score 0):

As fjh correctly stated, the array of strings `["$hello", "world"]` is rejoined into a string `"$hello world"` and `tail` then chops off the first Char `$`. I would recommend using the function `last` instead of `tail $ unwords` which will get the last element out of the array of words `world`.

```
Prelude> last $ words $ "$hello world"
"world"
```